# Capitalize a string

Tags: python, string

Does anyone know of a really simple way of capitalizing just the first letter of a string, regardless of the capitalization of the rest of the string?

For example:

```
asimpletest -> Asimpletest
aSimpleTest -> ASimpleTest
```

I would like to be able to do all string lengths as well.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

@[saua](https://stackoverflow.com/a/352494/2285236) is right, and

```
s = s[:1].upper() + s[1:]
```

will work for any string.

Comment: Nice! Those are the kind of little tricks that I don't know ... I should use Python more often.

Comment: Why not `s = s[0].upper() + s[1:]`?  Why the `[:1]`?

Comment: As @saua notes, `s[0]` will fail on an empty string.

Answer (score 142):

```
>>> b = "my name"
>>> b.capitalize()
'My name'
>>> b.title()
'My Name'
```

Comment: Using the standard library is def the way to go.

Comment: ... except capitalize() removes any other existing caps, which the questioner explicitly didn't want to happen: 'aSimpleTest'.capitalize() => 'Asimpletest'

Comment: @pfctdayelise .. are you down voting all answers not satisfying this requirement or just mine :) ? Though, I agree with your observation. Blair Conrad's answer is most precise. But, other answers add value in presenting useful information around string capitalization, including mine. Three of them were added later than the accepted answer.

Comment: @tigeronk2 I would call it "misleading" rather than "adding value",  when the answer doesn't meet the requirements explicitly stated in the question, especially when you don't point out the limitations of your approach.

Answer (score 11):

What about `your_string.title()`?

e.g. `"banana".title() -> Banana`

Comment: `str.title` capitalizes each _word_ in the string

Comment: @John La Rooy ...which is exactly what I wanted to do without writing a new def to split, capitalize each word, and put it back together...  upvote to skyler

Answer (score 8):

```
s = s[0].upper() + s[1:]
```

This should work with every string, except for the empty string (when `s=""`).

Comment: beat me to it, and yours is more elegant.

Answer (score 4):

this actually gives you a capitalized word, instead of just capitalizing the first letter

cApItAlIzE -> Capitalize

```
def capitalize(str): 
    return str[:1].upper() + str[1:].lower().......
```

Answer (score 2):

for capitalize first word;

```
a="asimpletest"
print a.capitalize()
```

for make all the string uppercase use the following tip;

```
print a.upper()
```

this is the easy one i think.

Answer (score 1):

Docs can be found here for string functions https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/string.html#string-functions
Below code capitializes first letter with space as a separtor

```
s="gf12 23sadasd"
print( string.capwords(s, ' ') )
```

> Gf12 23sadasd

Comment: this should be answer, since capitalize will cap only the first word

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [str.title()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) function to do that

```
In [1]: x = "hello"

In [2]: x.title()
Out[2]: 'Hello'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirements in the question. It capitalizes first letter but other chars are lowered. E.g. `'aSimpleTest'.capitalize() -> 'Asimpletest'`