# Python How to capitalize nth letter of a string

Tags: python, string, capitalize

I tried this: [*Capitalize a string*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352478/capitalize-a-string). Can anybody provide a simple script/snippet for guideline?

Python documentation has [`capitalize()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=capitalize#str.capitalize) function which makes first letter capital. I want something like `make_nth_letter_cap(str, n)`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Capitalize n-th character and lowercase the rest as [`capitalize()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) does:

```
def capitalize_nth(s, n):
    return s[:n].lower() + s[n:].capitalize()
```

Answer (score 14):

```
my_string[:n] + my_string[n].upper() + my_string[n + 1:]
```

Or a more efficient version that isn't a [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm):

```
''.join([my_string[:n], my_string[n].upper(), my_string[n + 1:]])
```

Comment: Here is some more information regarding string concatenation in python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python

Comment: in your case N=3 and therefore we can't be sure what implementation O(N) or O(N*N) would be more "efficient" (for such a small N). I don't know what is more efficient `''.join([a, b, c])`  or `a+b+c` (or is it even worth it to worry about the time it takes to concatenate a couple of string relative to other parts in a codebase).

Answer (score 2):

```
x = "string"
y = x[:3] + x[3].swapcase() + x[4:]
```

**Output**

```
strIng
```

[Code](http://codepad.org/84GSVftG)

Keep in mind that `swapcase` will invert the case whether it is lower or upper.
I used this just to show an alternate way.

Comment: I added a note below my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is the comprehensive solution: either you input a single word, a single line sentence or a multi line sentence, the nth letter will be converted to Capital letter and you will get back the converted string as output:

You can use this code:

```
def nth_letter_uppercase(string,n):
  
  listofwords = string.split()
  sentence_upper = ''

  for word in listofwords:
  
    length = len(word)
      
    if length > (n - 1):
      new_word = word[:n-1] + word[n-1].upper() + word[n:]
      
    else:
      new_word = word
          
    sentence_upper += ' ' + new_word

  return sentence_upper
```

calling the function defined above (I want to convert 2nd letter of each word to a capital letter):

```
string = '''nature is beautiful
and i love python'''
nth_letter_uppercase(string,2)
```

output will be:

```
'nAture iS bEautiful aNd i lOve pYthon'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old topic but this might be useful to someone in the future:

```
def myfunc(str, nth):
new_str = '' #empty string to hold new modified string
for i,l in enumerate(str): # enumerate returns both, index numbers and objects
    if i % nth == 0: # if index number % nth == 0 (even number)
        new_str += l.upper() # add an upper cased letter to the new_str
    else: # if index number nth
        new_str += l # add the other letters to new_str as they are
return new_str # returns the string new_str
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified answer would be:

```
    def make_nth_letter_capital(word, n):
        return word[:n].capitalize() + word[n:].capitalize()
```

Comment: Could you add short explanation what this code does

Answer (score 0):

```
def capitalize_n(string, n):
    return string[:n] + string[n].capitalize() + string[n+1:]
```

> This works perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
def capitalize_nth(text, pos):
    before_nth = text[:pos]
    n = text[pos].upper()
    new_pos = pos+1
    after_nth = text[new_pos:]
    word = before_nth + n + after_nth
    print(word)

capitalize_nth('McDonalds', 6)
```

The outcome is:

```
'McDonaLds'
```

I think this is the simplest among every answer up there...

Answer (score 0):

To capitalise the nth letter in the given string

```
def nth_letter_uppercase(string,n):

  listofwords = string.split()
  sentence_upper = ''

  for word in listofwords:

    length = len(word)
    

    if length > (n - 1):
      new_word = word[:n-1] + word[n-1].upper() + word[n:]
     

    else:
      new_word = word

    sentence_upper += ' ' + new_word
    H=sentence_upper[n-1:]

  return H

String=str(input("Enter String :"))

nth_letter_uppercase(String,2)  #n is named as 2 here you can use any value you want to change
```

Then in console screen

```
Enter String :hi here is your solution
hI hEre iS yUor sOlution
```

I had just polished the code by deleting the space infront of the string